# How to assure response even if rpc server goes down on rabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I was wondering if there's is a way to make the messages persistent in case the server fails?. If the client sends a message with no server running, it stays there awaiting for the response and it doesn't get anything once the server goes up again..

Having a configuration like this: 
[image: RPC client- server]

If the server disappears, is there a way to resume the process whenever the server is up again? A retry of the client or that the server gets the client request once is up again...  How could I do this? (the "durable = true" parameter doesn't accomplish this...)

The complete example and code is in [this rpc tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html).

Answer (score 1):

By itself, RabbtMQ doesn't provide an automated means for clients to store and resend messages when the broker is down.  According the the [reliablility documentation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html)

*...producers recovering from a channel or connection failure should retransmit any messages for which an acknowledgement has not been received from the broker.*

Your RabbitMQ client framework may provide something like that, for instance by storing messages locally on disk while the server is down, or you can build it yourself.

The other option is to set up [RabbitMQ clustering](http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) to reduce the chances of a total broker outage.